# Groovy Array initialization

Tags: java, groovy

I have a function that takes in input two BitSet, then, I invoke this function by *evaluate* in Groovy.
Since the params are two BitSet, I need to initialize them inline and to pass everything by a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
    path(BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {0b00111111}),BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {0b00000011})); //s3
    //String s1 = "path(BitSet.valueOf([0b00111111L] as long[]),BitSet.valueOf([0b00111111L] as long[]))";
    //String s2 = "path(BitSet.valueOf( long[] o = [0b00111111L] ),BitSet.valueOf( long[] oo = [0b00111111L] ))";
    String s3 = "path(BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {0b00111111}),BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {0b00000011}))";
    Object value = shell.evaluate(s3);


}

public static LinkedList<BitSet> path(BitSet dstBitSet, BitSet srcBitSet) {
    LinkedList<BitSet> l = new LinkedList<>();
    l.add(srcBitSet);
    System.out.println("ok");
    return l;
}
```

The third lines just call the function path with params and it works.
But, exactly the same piece of code (s3 var) in Groovy does not work because it returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main"  org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup   failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: No expression for the array constructor call at   line: 1 column: 29. File: Script1.groovy @ line 1, column 29.
path(BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {0b00111111}),BitSet.valueOf(new long[]     {0b00000011}))
                            ^
```

*Googling* I found out that Groovy accept the arrays inizialitation with the followings formats:

- [0b00111111] as long[]
- long[] o = [0b00111111]

As you can see by the code, I tried to do the same in the var s1 and s2, but still is not working.
S1 error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No   signature of method: Script1.path() is applicable for argument types:   (java.util.BitSet, java.util.BitSet) values: [{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1,   2, 3, 4, 5}]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), with(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure), run(), run()
```

S2 error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: Invalid use of declaration inside method call.
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path(BitSet.valueOf([0b00111111] as long[]), BitSet.valueOf([0b00111111] as long[]))
```